# How to get the deleted character and update my string inside textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying the get the string when the user starts typing with '@' and ends with '@'... So i went on with jquery .keydown() event. For example, if the i type '@testing@', i should retrieve the string 'testing' but the problem occurs if i delete any characters in my string using backspace or delete . I can able to capture the event but unfortunately cant able to figure out the deleted character and update my string...

and here is the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uyufiw/7/edit) i tried out...

Please help with some suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Use textarea.selectionStart:

```
textarea.value.substr(textarea.selectionStart-1,1)
```